# Why can't I vote to close this question?

Tags: bug, status-completed, vote-to-close

I recently happened across [this gem of a question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17890842/can-anyone-explain-classic-asp-vb6), and noticed that Ken White had already done much of my work for me by writing an extremely comprehensive and detailed close reason. But when I tried to piggyback off his labors, the system shot me down—repeatedly:

[image: Close -> As Off-Topic -> Select "Other" -> Click "Vote To Close" button, but "An error occurred; please try again"]

I've tried again…and again. Doesn't work.

I'm guessing that it is somehow related to that custom off-topic reason, because I have been successfully voting to close *other* questions on SO and Meta.

I've been hesitant to try closing this one for a *different* reason in case I need to demonstrate that the problem is reproducible.

Whuzzup?

Comment: Temporary workaround: voted to close as Too Broad.

Comment: But: reproduced. Eeeeeek!

Comment: @MartijnPieters I think you might be missing a couple of "E"'s in that Eeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeek.  Not being able to select that great reason is worth at least 23 "e"'s.  For the record, I was able to reproduce this as well.

Comment: What's up? The opposite of down. What we used to think was North when we were younger.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Sorry, it was my bad... we now store all flags and close votes in a new `Flags` table.  Its custom `Text` column was only 500 chars, instead of 600 (the normal max for post comments).

A fix has been deployed, so close vote away!

Comment: And the reason why the original close voter was able to put that large message was... he didn't!  The original "other" text was much shorter, then the comment was edited by its author.

Comment: I saw that the comment was edited, but when comparing it to the message pre-filled in the close box, I assumed that he only added the link to the "help center". Surely the close box doesn't pick up edits made to auto-generated comments?